# Free variables treated as globals in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global, free-variable

In the [*Execution Model* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) of the Python 3.7 reference manual I read the following statement:

> The `global` statement has the same scope as a name binding operation in the same block. If the nearest enclosing scope for a free variable contains a `global` statement, the free variable is treated as a global.

So I typed the following code into the Python Interpreter:

```
x =0
def func1():
    global x
    def func2():
        x = 1
    func2()
```

After calling `func1()` I would have expected the value of `x` in the global scope to change to `1`.

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = 1` in `func2` *is not a free variable*. It's just another local; you are binding to the name and names bound to are, by default, locals unless you tell Python otherwise.

From the [same *Execution model* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html):

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless declared as `nonlocal` or `global`. *[...]* **If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable.**

(*Bold emphasis mine*)

You bound the name in the block with `x = 1`, so it is a local variable in that block, and can't be a free variable. So section you found doesn't apply, because that would only apply to free variables:

> If the nearest enclosing scope **for a free variable** contains a `global` statement, the free variable is treated as a global.

You should not bind `x` in `func2()`, because only names that are *not* binding in the scope are free variables.

So this works:

```
>>> def func1():
...     global x
...     x = 1
...     def func2():
...         print(x)  # x is a free variable here
...     func2()
...
>>> func1()
1
>>> x
1
```

`x` in `func2` is now a free variable; it is not defined in the scope of `func2`, so picks it up from the parent scope. The parent scope here is `func1`, but `x` is marked a global there so when *reading* `x` for the `print()` function the global value is used.

Contrast this with `x` not being marked as a global in `func1`:

```
>>> def func1():
...     x = 1
...     def func2():
...         print(x)  # x is free variable here, now referring to x in func1
...     func2()
...
>>> x = 42
>>> func1()
1
```

Here the global name `x` is set to `42`, but this doesn't affect what is printed. `x` in `func2` is a free variable, but the parent scope `func1` only has `x` as a local name.

It becomes all the more *interesting* when you add a new outer-most scope where `x` is *still local*:

```
>>> def outerfunc():
...     x = 0   # x is a local
...     def func1():
...         global x   # x is global in this scope and onwards
...         def func2():
...             print('func2:', x)  # x is a free variable
...         func2()
...     print('outerfunc:', x)
...     func1()
...
>>> x = 42
>>> outerfunc()
outerfunc: 0
func2: 42
>>> x = 81
>>> outerfunc()
outerfunc: 0
func2: 81
```

`x` in `outerfunc` is bound, so not a free variable. It is therefore a local in that scope. However, in `func1`, the `global x` declaration marks `x` as a global in the nested scrope. In `func2` `x` is a free variable, and by the statement that you found, it is treated as a global.